# Что наследует RecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android

Что значит запись.

```
..   extends  RecyclerView.Adapter < RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder >
```

Как ее расшифровать и почему запись через точку, почему нельзя указать один конкретный класс, который делает то, что надо и использовать именно его, а здесь сделано c такими вложенностями - какое это дает преимущество может это какой-то эффективный паттерн ?

И

```
@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType)
```

Непонятно, что это за тип такой `RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder` в названии метода ?

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String[] mDataset;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
    }
}

// Конструктор
public RecyclerAdapter(String[] dataset) {
    mDataset = dataset;
}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);


    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
```

}

Comment: А почему запись через точку RecyclerView.Adapter  - это что значит ?

Comment: вопрос такой если так можно обращаться через точку в внутреннему классу то зачем тогда обращаться в внешнему классу  RecyclerView а не напрямую к нужному классу или запись через точку позволяет использовать таким образом множественное наследование ?

Comment: Так а зачем это делать я так и не понял, почему нельзя указать один конкретный класс который делает то что надо и использовать именно его ,а здесь сделано c такими вложенностями - какое это дает преимущество может это какой-то эффективный патерн ?

Answer (score 4):

Адаптер `RecyclerView` наследует [абстрактные вложенные классы](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hannesdorfmann.annotatedadapter/support-recyclerview-stub/1.1.0/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#RecyclerView), которым вам надо написать конкретную реализацию.

Метод `onCreateViewHolder()` возвращает объекты класса `ViewHolder`, реализацию которого вы напишите. Это будет тип состоящий из имени вашего класса адаптера и вложенной в него вашей реализации класса `ViewHolder`.

Так уж сложилось, что программист, писавший  виджет `RecyclerView`, посчитал уместным реализовать данный класс `Adapter`, как вложенный в основной класс `RecyclerView`. Вам не остается ничего, как смириться с этим. Можно было бы реализовать и отдельный класс, но поскольку класс `Adapter` абстрактный и не содержит никакой реализации, оформлять его отдельно сочли нецелесообразным, видимо, поэтому для реализации "каноничного" адаптера к виджету `RecyclerView` вам нужно наследоваться именно от его вложенного класса `Adapter` - запись `RecyclerView.Adapter` значит, что наследовать надо именно вложенный в `RecyclerView` класс `Adapter`, а никакой другой класс с аналогичным именем.

Никакой особой эффективности и прочих преимуществ (за исключением областей видимости статических переменных этих классов) такая реализация не дает, просто один из возможных способов. Подробнее о вложенных классах и их "преимуществах" вы можете прочитать, например [здесь](http://easy-code.ru/lesson/java-nested-classes).

Все эти вопросы входят в общие основы ООП и если вы все еще не достаточно понимаете, что и зачем здесь происходит, рекомендую почитать книгу по этой дисциплине, например: Б.Эккель - Философия Java, она вам очень сильно поможет понимать, что же происходит, почему именно так и как можно иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы создать адаптер для RecyclerView, нужно наследоваться от RecyclerView.Adapter. Этот адаптер представляет шаблон проектирования ViewHolder, подразумевающий использование пользовательского класса, который расширяет RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Эта паттерн сводит к минимуму количество обращений к дорогостоящему в плане ресурсов методу findViewById.

Более детальную информацию можете найти по [этой ссылке](http://www.fandroid.info/primer-ispolzovaniya-cardview-i-recyclerview-v-android/).

Answer (score 1):

До введения RecyclerView использование патерна ViewHolder носило рекомендательный характер.Теперь же c RecyclerView его использование является обязательным. При этом обязательно должны быть переопределены методы: onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder, getItemCount